# Quadratic Reciprocity as a consequence of Eisenstein Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I was recently looking at the wikipedia page on Eisenstein Reciprocity, which says it "extends Quadratic Reciprocity." However, though the two do seem to be related, I don't completely understand how Eisenstein Reciprocity implies Quadratic Reciprocity. Can someone give me an explanation about why Eisenstein reciprocity implies quadratic reciprocity, or possibly cubic and quartic reciprocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Theorem $12.8$, Corollary $12.9$ etc. in the following [text](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/rl2/rlb12.pdf) of Franz Lemmermayer, who is an expert for reciprocity laws. There are many articles explaining also various consequences of Eisenstein's and Artin's reciprocity law.